# Magento catalog URL rewrite indexing taking too long

Tags: magento, indexing, magento-1.7

I've been dealing with this problem with around *10k+ products* in two store views in magento 1.7.

The **URL indexing process** took around **30 hours** to change its state to ready. Also i found multiple entries of the same product being made in the **core_url_rewrite** table and the number of rows now reached upto **6500k**.

This is causing **deadlocks**. I tried clearing the locks but that didn't help. Is there a workaround solution for this problem as this is magento core functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There's some good general advice on [the Magento Stack Exchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/permanent-solution-for-the-common-indexing-issue) covering common indexing problems.

It's also common for larger store to create a rewrite/code-pool-override for the following method

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php
protected function _getProducts($productIds, $storeId, $entityId, &$lastEntityId)
{
    //...
}
```

This method queries for the products that need a URL reindex. By default, this includes **all** simple and configurable products.  However, if you're not displaying simple products individually, you can tweak this query to not include those products.  That can greatly reduce the number of URLs Magento needs to generate.